# How can use AsyncStorage in string template

Tags: javascript, react-native

```
//await is not working in string template is there any other way to use AsyncStorage 
   
 export const http = new HttpService(BASE_URL, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken')}`,
    })
```

And without await promise is not resolved how can I fix this please help

Comment: Can you provide a little bit more code of where this is used, because from the looks of it this is a static constant built on app initialisation (when there isn't anything in storage) that never changes afterwards. If so, just convert it into a "getter-like" function, e.g. `export cont getHttp = () => new HttpService(..)`

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way I see is to simply use a variable to first get the token from AsyncStorage and then use it in your request. Hence, your code would be something like: -

```
const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
const http = new new HttpService(BASE_URL, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    })
```

You might also have to make a function, something like: -

```
const request = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');
    const http = new HttpService(BASE_URL, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        });
}
```